# org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type while fetching data

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am trying to fetch some search result from a database table 'Question' by querying with a keyword (bind in the form by 'course-code'). The target is to get the results from the table from the column with a foreign key 'Course_coursecode' which is a string value. Here is my code snippet:

```
    @Transactional
            @RequestMapping(value = "/question-list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
            public ModelAndView viewQuestionList(@RequestParam("course-code")String code, ModelAndView model){

                    model.setViewName("question-list");

                    Question question = em.find(com.databaseproject.questor.model.Question.class, code);
                    model.addObject("question", question);

                    List<Question> questions = 

(List<Question>)em.createQuery("SELECT q FROM Question q WHERE q.Course_coursecode =: code")
                        .setParameter("code", code).getResultList();

                model.addObject("questionList", questions);

                return model;
        }
```

Now when I search with a string in the form i.e: 'CSE137' I get:

> org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type for class com.databaseproject.questor.model.Question. Expected: class java.lang.Integer, got class java.lang.String
>
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Provided id of the wrong type for class com.databaseproject.questor.model.Question. Expected: class java.lang.Integer, got class java.lang.String
>
> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Provided id of the wrong type for class com.databaseproject.questor.model.Question. Expected: class java.lang.Integer, got class java.lang.String

Interestingly, when I enter an int value as the search query, I get this:

> org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type for class com.databaseproject.questor.model.Question. Expected: class java.lang.Integer, got class java.lang.String
>
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Provided id of the wrong type for class com.databaseproject.questor.model.Question. Expected: class java.lang.Integer, got class java.lang.String
>
> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Provided id of the wrong type for class com.databaseproject.questor.model.Question. Expected: class java.lang.Integer, got class java.lang.String

What am I doing wrong here? How can I fix it?

Update:
Here is my entity class-

```
package com.databaseproject.questor.model;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Transient;

@Entity
public class Question {

    @Id
    private int idQuestion;
    private String questionText;
    private String solutionText;
    private byte[] image;
    private String filepath;
    private int year;
    private String User_username;
    private int Teacher_idTeacher;
    private String Course_coursecode;

    @Transient
    private String encodedImage;

    public int getIdQuestion() {
        return idQuestion;
    }

    public void setIdQuestion(int idQuestion) {
        this.idQuestion = idQuestion;
    }

    public String getQuestionText() {
        return questionText;
    }

    public void setQuestionText(String questionText) {
        this.questionText = questionText;
    }

    public String getSolutionText() {
        return solutionText;
    }

    public void setSolutionText(String solutionText) {
        this.solutionText = solutionText;
    }

    public byte[] getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(byte[] image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getFilepath() {
        return filepath;
    }

    public void setFilepath(String filepath) {
        this.filepath = filepath;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public String getUser_username() {
        return User_username;
    }

    public void setUser_username(String user_username) {
        User_username = user_username;
    }

    public int getTeacher_idTeacher() {
        return Teacher_idTeacher;
    }

    public void setTeacher_idTeacher(int teacher_idTeacher) {
        Teacher_idTeacher = teacher_idTeacher;
    }

    public String getCourse_coursecode() {
        return Course_coursecode;
    }

    public void setCourse_coursecode(String course_coursecode) {
        Course_coursecode = course_coursecode;
    }

    public String getEncodedImage() {
        return encodedImage;
    }

    public void setEncodedImage(String encodedImage) {
        this.encodedImage = encodedImage;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is unclear in the error message? You're trying to find a Question by ID. A Question's ID is of type Integer. But you're passing `code` as argument to `em.find()`, and code is of type String. Hence the exception.

Comment: @JBNizet has a point, but please post your entity class for more details

Comment: I have updated the question adding the entity class. Please check it. @JBNizet.

Comment: Updated the question. Posted the entity class. Can you please check it? @Baldurian.

Comment: And my answer is still the same: you're passing a String to em.find(), but the ID od Question is of type `int`, hence the exception. Just read the error message. The argument of em.find() ust be of type Integer. Not String.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Watching the entity, as pointed out by @JB Nizet, you are trying to find a Question occurence by id

```
Question question = em.find(com.databaseproject.questor.model.Question.class, code);
```

passing "code" that is a String. If "code" represent the id you should convert it into a int:

```
model.setViewName("question-list");
int id = 0;
try
{
    if(code != null)
      id = Integer.parseInt(code);
}
catch (NumberFormatException e)
{
    id = 0;
}
Question question = em.find(com.databaseproject.questor.model.Question.class, id);
```

handling also a possible not found Question. If "code" isn't the id, you should make a query (with criteria, native or jpql) to get a list of Question entities picking up the one you need.

Edit -> to get a list of Question entities:

```
TypedQuery<Question> query = em.createQuery("SELECT q FROM Question q WHERE q.Course_coursecode = :coursecode", Question.class);
query.setParameter("coursecode", code);
List<Question> results = query.getResultList();
```

Comment: 'coursecode' is a column in a table named 'Course', it is the primary and it's string value. I have this in the other table name 'Question' as the foreign key. There is no int. I want to search for the occurrences with a string value for say 'CSE137'. Assume there are rows where I have: CSE136, CSE445, CSE987, CSE137, CSE137... in the Course_coursecode column. If I want to get the occurrences of CSE137 what should I do, or, what are the changes I need to implement in my code?